# Why there is infinite loop?c++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, infinite

```
do{
    cout << "your number"; cin >> z;


   if (z > 4){
    cout << "invalid answer" << endl;}
   else if (z == 4){
   cout << " no" << endl;}
   else {
   cout  <<"great!"   << endl; }
} while (z != 3, 2, 1);
}
```

In my oppinion it's: bring up "your number" until z is 3 or 2 or 1? What's wrong?'

Comment: `(z != 3, 2, 1)` is using comma operator. It evaluates the left hand expression and discards the results, then evaluates the right hand expression and returns the result. So your loop condition is equivalent to `while (1)`;

Comment: Look up the comma operator and operator precedence. Your `while` condition does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Yet another candidate who failed to read through the tutorial until the comma operator...

Comment: `while (z != 3, 2, 1)` evaluates to: `while(1)` as the comma operator evaluates all the expressions and returns the last.

Answer (score 5):

```
while (z != 3, 2, 1);
```

Your while condition is wrong, it should be:

```
while (z != 3 && z != 2 && z != 1);
```

If you use the commas, it will evaluate (calculate) all the expressions separated by them, and will use the last expression.

In this case

```
(z != 3, 2, 1)
```

It will evaluate z != 3, then 2 and finally will use 1, your while would look like this:

```
while(1);
```

Which is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may falls on the while condition. The return value of your expression `"z != 3, 2, 1"` will evaluate to "1", which means true in C++. So there will be a infinite loop. Try to rewrite the cond. exp. like `"z != 3 || z != 2 || z != 1"`.